# Solve denominator so quotient is whole number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, divisibility

I have a simple equation.

```
road_length = ROADLENGTH / ROADSPACING
```

The problem is, I really need road_length to be a whole number because it's used in FOR loop in C++. Currently ROADLENGTH is 78.539 and I can't change it. ROADSPACING is how far one road segment is from the next and is the only other part of the equation I can adjust.

My question is, without guessing and checking a thousand times, is there a way to mathematically solve what ROADSPACING needs to be in order to get road_length to be a whole number? Keep in mind ROADLENGTH will change from road to road, so it's not always going to be 78.539. ROADSPACING is currently 0.1.

Comment: Are there any restrictions to the integer values that road_length can take? If not, one way I can think of is to multiply both sides of equation with 10^n such that ROADLENGTH becomes an integer, let's call that int_RL, then proceed to find factors of int_RL so you can use any of the factor as your integer value for road_length.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, apart from reducing ROADSPACING to 0.00001, in which case in may convert ROADLENGTHs having upto 5 places of decimal into whole numbers.

Comment: @jh4, There are no restrictions on road_length. That's a pretty good idea. Currently trying that out.

Comment: Haha, well it turns out the only factors of 78539 are 1 and itself. Crap. 78539 / 1000 = 78.539... the same problem. That's why I was thinking about scaling .1 (the denominator) to something else so it works.

Comment: Could you have a ROADSPACING of 0.000000000001? Will take care of almost everything you need.

Comment: No that is way too small. The road vertices would practically be on top of each other and make for a very, very dense mesh. Units are in meters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
integer = (int)(ROADLENGTH / ROADSPACING) // Equals 785
result = ROADLENGTH / integer // Equals 0.10004968152866242038216560509554

road_length = ROADLENGTH / result; //Equals ~785.0 (very, very close)
```

I actually get the (int) casting for the last step so it is 785 on the dot, but I didn't want to confuse anyone.